# Undefined method using ternary operators in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, ternary

trying to write two methods in the same file to check number arguments. The first method passes all tests fine but the second keeps giving me the NoMethodError even though the method by its self passes.

heres my code:

```
def unsafe?(speed)
        if speed < 40 
            return true
        elsif speed > 60
            return true 
        else
            return false
end

def not_safe?(speed)
        speed < 40 || speed > 60 ? true : false
    end
end
```

Comment: Please add stacktrace of error

Answer (score 4):

You're missing an `end` keyword to `if`. This is what it looks like if you indent the code properly:

```
def unsafe?(speed)
  if speed < 40 
    return true
  elsif speed > 60
    return true 
  else
    return false
  end
  
  def not_safe?(speed)
    speed < 40 || speed > 60 ? true : false
  end
end
```

As you can see the code will never get to `def not_safe?(speed)` as the method has already returned. Ruby allows nested method definitions yet their actual use is [universally discouraged](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-nested-methods).

This is what it should look like:

```
def unsafe?(speed)
  if speed < 40 
    return true
  elsif speed > 60
    return true 
  else
    return false
  end
end

def not_safe?(speed)
  speed < 40 || speed > 60 ? true : false
end
```

But this is really is a very overcomplicated way of doing something that can be handled with:

```
def unsafe?(speed)
  !speed.between(40,60)
end
```

The whole idea of using the ternary operator is just plain strange as `speed < 40 || speed > 60` evaluates to true or false anyways.

Comment: An even more expressive alternative might be `!speed.between?(40, 60)`